# famous Euler sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, euler-sums

Does anyone know how Euler in the 18th century proved that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{n^2}=2 \zeta(3)
$$
with $H_n$ being the *$n$'th* *harmonic number*?

Comment: Are you asking for Euler's proof specifically, or just any proof?

Comment: I was actually asking for the classic approach. From the answers I reckon he did the more general formula with q instead of the square.

Comment: The linked question _explicitly_ asked for Euler's approach.